# Activity changes slowly or not at all with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with an amount of elements, which can increase and decrease over time. One element is a LinearLayout with 9 Buttons inside.
If I have many elements inside the RecyclerView (more than 1000) and want to go back with the normal back button this does not work, the screen gets black and nothing more happens. The same is happening when I try to restart the activity

```
Intent pl = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(pl);
```

This is how I initialize the RecyclerView:

```
        ArrayList<RecycleViewData> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSet.add(new RecycleViewData(text, tag, width, status, scaledDensity, hilfe));

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(dataSet, mListener, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In the activity more elements are added (or removed) to the dataSet later.

If I have not that many elements all works as expected. What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Comment: Show your recyclerView initialization code also, this information is not sufficient enough to identify your problem.